# How can i allign right block on the top with bootstrap on mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have such code:

```
<div class="row inner">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h1>image is here...</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h2>Add</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <h3>text1</h3>
          <p><span>BlaBlaBla1</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <h3>text2</h3>
          <p><span>BlaBlaBla2</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and so it looks like on mobile:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABZeL.png)

but i need that my second column appears on the top on mobile (not on the bottom)...

can i achieve it somehow without changing html code?

plunker:  https://plnkr.co/edit/BKPhHxbZO0VQnubblh7f?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If using bootstrap why not just add push and pull classes? If you do not want to modify the markup you could do this javascript also. Why would you not want to modify the markup?

```
<div class="row inner">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
        <h2>Add</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <h3>text1</h3>
          <p><span>BlaBlaBla1</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <h3>text2</h3>
          <p><span>BlaBlaBla2</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
        <h1>image is here...</h1>
      </div>
</div>
```

edit

Also, If you want to right align something in bootstrap for a particular media query add it to the stylesheet. So on mobile it would be `text-align: right` and on your next media to reset it you can add `text-align: left`